# Code repeats with require_once()

Tags: php, require-once

I'm trying to setup my own raw access log for just one test file for each visitor. I can successfully read in the server log file, add one line to it and save it back to the server. Here's the snag. If I make a link to any external style sheet or javascript, the PHP script adds one line for every external link. If I link to three style sheets and two javascripts, you would think I had five visitors. If this has been answered, please redirect.

```
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  $path .= "/xxxxxxxxxx.php";
  require_once($path);
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are doing exactly. I don't see any css file in your example. Maybe post some more code on what are you doing exactly would help to determine.

Comment: Finally! I got this to work.

session_start();
$ip1 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SESSION['REFERENCE'] = $ip1;
require_once('xxxxxxxx.php');

Comment: Thats nice, you could maybe share your solution so others could benefit from it in the future.